# Arreglo de input en controlador solo me toma el ultimo valor al registrar en la BD / Laravel

Tags: laravel

Estoy trabajando con una tabla que genera a través de un foreach los inputs, cuando pruebo los valores que me trae el input con "RETURN DD($REQUEST->ppm) me muestra el arreglo completo con los datos rellenados, pero cuando quiero registrar en la BD solo me registra el ultimo valor del arreglo.

Igual esta edición va en la tabla hija, que es la de detalle por decirlo asi, por lo cual solo posee claves foraneas y no clave primaria

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**VISTA**

```
            <table class="table table-responsive">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Tipo de Analisis</th>
                        <th>PPM de la muestra</th>
                        <th>Estado examen</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach($resultadoAnalisis as $analisis)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{$analisis->nombre_analisis}}</td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    @if(isset($analisis->PPM) )
                                        <input type="text" id="ppm" name="ppm[]" class="form-control text-center" value="{{$analisis->PPM}}" onkeypress="return validarNumeros(event)"/>
                                    @else
                                        <input type="text" id="ppm" name="ppm[]" class="form-control text-center"  onkeypress="return validarNumeros(event)"/>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @foreach ($estados as $estado)
                                    @if($analisis->estado_id != 3)
                                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="estadoExamen" name="estadoExamen[]" value="{{$estado->id_estadoResultado}}">
                                            <label class="form-check-label" for="estadoExamen">{{$estado->tipo_estado}}</label>
                                        </div>
                                    @else
                                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="estadoExamen" name="estadoExamen[]" value="{{$estado->id_estadoResultado}}" checked>
                                            <label class="form-check-label" for="estadoExamen">{{$estado->tipo_estado}}</label>
                                        </div>
                                    @endif 
                                @endforeach
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Eso si debo decir que me registra los datos pero me duplica los valores del input.

**CONTROLADOR**

```
public function update(Request $request,$id)
    {
        try{
            DB::beginTransaction();
            $muestraID = Crypt::decrypt($id);

            $resultado2 = ResultadoAnalisis::join('analisis_muestra','resultado_analisis.muestra_id','=','analisis_muestra.id_analisisMuestra')
            ->where('id_analisisMuestra','=',$muestraID)->get();

            foreach ($resultado2 as $x) {
                if ($x->empleado_rut == null) {
                    DB::update('update resultado_analisis set empleado_rut = ?,estado_id = ? where muestra_id = ?', [Session('idEmpleado'),2,$muestraID]);
                }

                //Arreglo de Input en vista con nombre name="ppm[]"
                foreach ($request->ppm as $resultadoPPM) {
                    DB::update('update resultado_analisis set PPM = ?, estado_id = ?,fecha_registro = ? where muestra_id = ?', [$resultadoPPM,3,Carbon::now(),$muestraID]);

                    if ($x->PPM == null) {
                        DB::update('update resultado_analisis set estado_id = ? where muestra_id = ?', [2,$muestraID]);
                    }
                } 
            }     

            DB::commit();
            notify()->success('Muestra recepcionada con exito','Exito!!.',  ['timeOut' => 10000]);
            return redirect('/dashboard');
        } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
            notify()->warning('Error al modificar');
            DB::rollback();
            return redirect('/dashboard');
        } catch (QueryException $ex){
            notify()->error('Error al realizar la consulta en la BD');
            DB::rollback();
            return redirect('/dashboard');
        }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tuve que trabajar por arreglos y con for y no con foreach,, obtener solo el ID, agregare el campo ID y pasar a un arreglo y asi recorrerlo.